# How to filter users home directories to get a list of users with a symbolic link - see picture

Tags: command-line, permissions, ls

I'm doing a basic Linux course and as you can see in the picture I'm supposed to enter in a command or command chain to get the output shown in the picture. anyone know the command I would use to get the desired result? ls -la /home/* gets me close but I'm not sure what I need to use to filter it.

[image: how to filter]

Comment: That may fit better at unix.se

Comment: No, it won't, at least not as it is now. This question is not answerable, because we don't know what's in the home folders. Depending on the context, there are a lot of possible answers. We can only guess...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `find` command is the better way to do this, but if you have to use `ls`, you can use

```
ls -la /home/* | grep '^l'
```

Comment: I don't have to use ls that's just what I thought would do it. Out of curiosity, what would be the find command?

Comment: depends on what you are looking for, but `find /home -name "web" -type l `

Comment: Apart from that [you should not parse `ls`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead), this does not give the output from above.